# Convergence of product of sequences

Tags: sequences-and-series

Let $r \ge 0$ and $r^ncos(nθ+Β) \to0$ while $n$ goes to infinity. Does that mean that $r^n \to 0$?

Instinctively something sends the sequence to $0$ but I fail to show it.

Comment: Note that $-1 \leq \cos(n\theta + B) \leq 1$. I'm also not sure that it is always the case that $r^n \to 0$ if $r^n\cos(n\theta+B) \to 0$.

Comment: No. Try $B=\frac\pi2$, $\theta=\pi$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint: I assume $n$ is an integer, what happen if $B={\pi\over 2}$ and $\theta =2\pi$ and take an value for $r$ ?